# Unable to connect to kubernetes python api - .kube/config file not found

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes, minikube

I'm having trouble connecting to the kubernetes python client even though I'm following the examples [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/example1.py) in the api.

Basically this line can't connect to the kubernetes client:

```
config.load_kube_config()
```

**What I'm doing:**

I have a Dockerfile file like this that I'm building my image with. This is just a simple python/flask app.

```
FROM python:2

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.8.1
kubernetes==6.0.0
requests # Apache-2.0
```

After building the Dockerfile it outputs:

```
    Successfully built a2590bae9fd9
    Successfully tagged testapp:latest
```

but when I do `docker run a2590bae9fd9` I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 10, in <module>
    config.load_kube_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 470, in load_kube_config
    config_persister=config_persister)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 427, in     _get_kube_config_loader_for_yaml_file
    with open(filename) as f:
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.kube/config'
```

I thought it might've been my python directory but I checked and its running in /usr/local/bin/python.

I'm really stumped - any suggestions/tips? thank you.

Comment: It's trying to load `'/root/.kube/config'` and that file doesn't exist in your container. Were you expecting it to exist? Where are you expecting it to load your config from?

Comment: I have the ~/.kube/config file locally so I guess I wrongly assumed it could use that  when kubernetes installs through requirements.txt. how can I make it read the config file I have locally on my computer, is that possible through the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't want `config.load_kube_config()`, you want [`config.load_incluster_config()`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/6.0.0/examples/in_cluster_config.py#L21)

If you need to distinguish between your setup and when it's running in a `Pod`, one mechanism is `if os.getenv('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST'): config.load_incluster_config()` since that for sure will be in the environment while in a `Pod`, and is unlikely to be in your local environment.

Comment: I just surround load_kube_config in try/catch and then use the load_incluster_config but your way is better

Comment: that worked! I used the incluster one before but didn't have the if statement so I guess that was what I was missing. thank you!

Comment: I've actually been getting "kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Service host/port is not set" error now on this config.load_incluster_config() line. do you have any suggestions on what I can do to fix it?

Comment: under what circumstances do you get that error, since my suggestion was to use 50% of what that exact error is complaining about: `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` (with the other 50% being `_PORT')