# accessing kubernetes python api through a pod

Tags: python, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-python-client

so I need to connect to the python kubernetes client through a pod. I've been trying to use `config.load_incluster_config()`, basically following the example from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/in_cluster_config.py). However it's throwing these errors.

```
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/kubernetes/config/incluster_config.py", line 93, in   load_incluster_config
  cert_filename=SERVICE_CERT_FILENAME).load_and_set()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site- packages/kubernetes/config/incluster_config.py", line 45, in load_and_set
  self._load_config()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/kubernetes/config/incluster_config.py", line 51, in _load_config
  raise ConfigException("Service host/port is not set.")
```

I'm using Python 2.7 and Minikube 
Any hints or suggestions would be really appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> so I need to connect to that pod somehow through the python api

I am pretty sure you misunderstood [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51035715/225016), and/or I misunderstood your question. One should only use `load_incluster_config` when ... in-cluster ... otherwise it will attempt to use `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/etcetc` and not find them (above and beyond the missing env-var in the actual error you cited above). However, if you had guarded the `load_incluster_config()` with the `if os.getenv('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST'):` as suggested, then it wouldn't run that code and this question here wouldn't be a problem.

If you have built a docker image, but *did not deploy it into kubernetes*, then that wasn't clear.

---

If you just want to use the python api to *access* the cluster, but not from *within* the cluster, `config.load_kube_config()` is in fact the correct method call, but you will absolutely need to provide a working `kubeconfig`, whether at `/root/.kube/config` or at another place specified by the env-var `KUBECONFIG` (I mean, usually; I haven't specifically looked into the python library to see if that env-var is honored).