# Access Kubernetes from another machine using Python

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a test Kubernetes cluster (Minikube) running in a Docker container.

I want to write some Python code to start jobs on that cluster. If I go inside the container:

```
$ docker exec -it kubernetes /bin/sh
#/ apk add python3
#/ apk add py3-pip
#/ pip install kubernertes
#/ pyhton3
>>> from kubernetes import config, client

>>> config.load_kube_config()
```

It works, and I can then create a client and do my stuff.

However, if I run the same Python commands from the host machine:

```
>>> config.load_kube_config()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/python/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 814, in load_kube_config
    loader = _get_kube_config_loader(
  File "/path/to/python/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 773, in _get_kube_config_loader
    raise ConfigException(
kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found.
```

That sort of makes sense, since kubernetes is not running on the machine. How do I go around this ? Is there another way to fetch the config file ?

Comment: havent you tried use [config.load_incluster_config()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51035715/9929015) ?

Comment: Isn't that for when you are running code in a Pod ?

Answer (score -1):

config should be in `~/.kube/config` path

```
mkdir -p ~/.kube/
cp <current config path> ~/.kube/config
#below steps verify  if your config is proper
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config 
kubectl get pods
```

once above steps are working fine you could try running the python script

Comment: Kubernetes is NOT on the machine. It runs in a container. My question is about using Python to send queries to that instance from outside the container.